# Efficient transactions between HTTP calls

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jdbc, transactions

I am developing a Spring Boot app and I have a method which calls external APIs and writes to the database. This is the structure:

```
method() {
   call external API
   save to DB
   call another external API
   save to DB
}
```

I tried putting the `@Transactional` annotation on the method signature but I realized it is inefficient. So I found another way: to use the `TransactionTemplate` object to encapsulate the DB writes programmatically in a transaction.

I need to cancel writing to the DB whatever errors occur on the method. So if the second call to the external API fails I have to roll back to the first write. Just as if the second writing to the DB fails, I have to cancel the first one. How can I do? Basically I need to get the effect of using the `@Transactional` annotation with a more efficient implementation.

Now I'm trying in this way:

```
method() {
       call external API
       transactionTemplate.execute(status -> save to DB);
       call another external API
       transactionTemplate.executeWithoutResult(status -> save to DB);
    }
```

But I noticed that the two transactions are not "linked":

```
method() {
           call external API
           transactionTemplate.execute(status -> save to DB);
           call another external API
           if(true) throw new RuntimeException(); // first write not rolled back
           transactionTemplate.executeWithoutResult(status -> save to DB);
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean "I realized it is inefficient"?

Comment: This guide says (rightly in my opinion) not to use the annotation in these cases: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-programmatic-transaction-management

Comment: Why don't you call both apis first and do both saves in one transaction?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do it. The second write uses the results of the second call.

Comment: Leaving a transaction open during an external api call will lock database resources for as long as that external api call takes. This is actually not a good practice.

Comment: Sure you can do it if "The second write uses the results of the second call."

Comment: In fact, that's exactly why I'm writing this post: I have to open transactions only when necessary, but the second must be "linked" to the first. If the second fails, I have to cancel the first as well.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli The first call and first write must precede. In particular, the first writing is used to understand if the entire operation is lawful. The second write (it is actually an UPDATE) must go after, taking the results of the second call. The first HTTP call is used to understand if the operation is legal for the first writing.

Comment: Sure but you can call both APIs first and then decide of the outcome of both calls for the writes

Comment: The second call in reality triggers a creation to another system. Unfurtunately, the order cannot be changed.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the exact use case